# How to display layout in Jetpack Navigation when using Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I started using Jetpack Compose and I'm very happy with it. I replaced a couple of layouts that where defined in xml by a `@Composable` function.

When I went back to my Navigation-xml I noticed that the preview inside every screen is done with **`tools:layout`** property. And property reference to a layout in xml. Not to an `@Composable` function.

Is there already a way to reference to a `@Composable` function from **`tools:layout`** in a Navigation xml so that the preview of my entire flow will be visible?

Comment: Navigation does not support Compose. When it does, I expect that it will be via the Kotlin DSL, not the XML `navigation` resource.

Comment: seems like this is still unavoidable because even google sample https://github.com/android/sunflower still has the same issue  in class tools:layout="@layout/fragment_plant_detail"> which is @composable and there is no solution yet.